# Variable value in ngClass directive - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have this ngClass directive to give a certain colour to a certain field of a table:

```
[ngClass]="{'sem_exam_ini' : row.dias_expir >= 9999, 'exam_prox_expir' : row.dias_expir > -90 && row.dias_expir < 0, 'exam_expir' : row.dias_expir > 0 }"
```

That row.dias_expir > **-90** it's not a fixed value, rather a variable number.

I tried to concatenate strings and binding values but throws errors. 
Every answer on the Internet didn't solve anything...

I wonder if I can add a kind of binding or string concatenation in order to add a variable there. It's possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you not create a variable for -90 and use it in your condition. Did you try?

Comment: Have you try row?.dias_expir >=999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change that -90 for a variable value inside your class without problem, for example calling it 'offset'

```
[ngClass]="{'sem_exam_ini' : row.dias_expir >= 9999, 'exam_prox_expir' : row.dias_expir > offset && row.dias_expir < 0, 'exam_expir' : row.dias_expir > 0 }"
```

Check this fiddle with variable values for both https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/10887/